# Android Calendar Layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, calendar, android-studio

My calendar layout looks something like this:

```
A B C D E F G

A B C D E F G

A B C D E F G

A B C D
```

I would like to make it that the first day of the calendar to start, for example, from the forth element's position (this implementation should be available only for the first row of the calendar) like this:

```
 blank A B C D

A B C D E F

A B C D E F

A B C D E F
```

I have a GridView for this, which is is using a RelativeLayout with a Button in it that has as a background another layout, that shouldn't be relevant right now.

Any advice...? Thanks :)

Comment: HelpFul For u http://droidwalk.blogspot.in/2012/11/android-calendar-sample.html

Comment: Forgot to mention that in my calendar, I don't output days of previous or following month, just current one.

Comment: *Any advice...?* - you could insert some blank cell days at the start to offset the starting position.

Comment: cheers, Luksprog! Will try that one out :) Although I'm not really sure how I should add that "nothing" as trailing month days

Comment: You didn't say anything about your adapter's implementation but if for example you pass it a list of some item you would add(at the first position) some dummy items so the total number of items in that list is a multiple of 7(and then pass it to the adapter). You may need to make some other changes to the adapter to make those item visually blank, not selectable etc

Comment: I added my implementation of the adapter, if you could take a look, I'd appreciate :)

Answer (score 0):

You this function while before you notifies you data set change.

```
public void refreshDays() {
        // clear items
        items.clear();
        flagDepartureDate = false;
        flagArrivalDate = false;

        int lastDay = month.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int firstDay = month.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        Calendar temp = (Calendar) month.clone();
        temp.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);

        Calendar temp2 = (Calendar) month.clone();
        temp2.add(Calendar.MONTH, +1);

        int lastDay_prev = temp.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        /*
         * if(((firstDay-1)+lastDay)>35) {
         */
        calDay.days = new String[42];
        calDay.month = new int[42];
        calDay.year = new int[42];
        /*
         * } else{ calDay.days = new String[35]; calDay.month = new int[35];
         * calDay.year = new int[35]; }
         */

        // Log.i("LAST DAY", lastDay+"");
        // Log.i("LAST DAY PREV", lastDay_prev+"");
        // Log.i("FIRST DAY", firstDay+"");
        // Log.i("FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK", FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK+"");
        int start_blanks = 0;
        int j = FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK;

        // populate empty days before first real day
        if (firstDay > 1) {
            for (j = 0; j < firstDay - FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK - 1; j++) {

                calDay.days[j] = ""
                        + (lastDay_prev - (firstDay - FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK - 1)
                                + j + 1);
                calDay.month[j] = temp.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                calDay.year[j] = temp.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                start_blanks += 1;
            }
        } else {
            for (j = 0; j < FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK * 6; j++) {
                calDay.days[j] = "";
            }
            j = FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK * 6; // sunday => 1, monday => 7
        }
        // Log.i("START_BLANK", start_blanks+"");
        // populate days
        int dayNumber = 1;
        for (int i = j; i < (lastDay + start_blanks); i++) {
            calDay.days[i] = "" + dayNumber;
            calDay.month[i] = month.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            calDay.year[i] = month.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            dayNumber++;
        }

        // populate empty days before first real day
        for (int i = (lastDay + start_blanks), k = 1; i < calDay.days.length; i++, k++) {
            calDay.days[i] = "" + k;
            calDay.month[i] = temp2.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            calDay.year[i] = temp2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        }

    }
```

Here "month" is the object of current calendar month

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class GridCellAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
            private static final String tag = "GridCellAdapter";
            private final Context _context;

            private final List<String> list;
            private static final int DAY_OFFSET = 1;
            private final String[] weekdays = new String[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue",
                    "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
            private final String[] months = { "JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH",
                    "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER",
                    "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER" };
            private final int[] daysOfMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30,
                    31, 30, 31 };
            private int daysInMonth;
            private int currentDayOfMonth;
            private int currentWeekDay;
            private Button gridcell;
            private TextView num_events_per_day;
            private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "dd-MMM-yyyy");

            // Days in Current Month
            public GridCellAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                                   int month, int year) {
                super();
                this._context = context;
                this.list = new ArrayList<String>();
                Log.d(tag, "==> Passed in Date FOR Month: " + month + " "
                        + "Year: " + year);
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                setCurrentDayOfMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                setCurrentWeekDay(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
                Log.d(tag, "New Calendar:= " + calendar.getTime().toString());
                Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfWeek :" + getCurrentWeekDay());
                Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfMonth :" + getCurrentDayOfMonth());

                // Print Month
                printMonth(month, year);

            }

 private void printMonth(int mm, int yy) {
            Log.d(tag, "==> printMonth: mm: " + mm + " " + "yy: " + yy);
            int trailingSpaces = 0;
            int daysInPrevMonth = 0;
            int prevMonth = 0;
            int prevYear = 0;
            int nextMonth = 0;
            int nextYear = 0;

            int currentMonth = mm - 1;
            String currentMonthName = getMonthAsString(currentMonth);
            daysInMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(currentMonth);

            Log.d(tag, "Current Month: " + " " + currentMonthName + " having "
                    + daysInMonth + " days.");

            GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(yy, currentMonth, 1);
            Log.d(tag, "Gregorian Calendar:= " + cal.getTime().toString());

            if (currentMonth == 11) {
                prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
                daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
                nextMonth = 0;
                prevYear = yy;
                nextYear = yy + 1;
                Log.d(tag, "*->PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                        + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                        + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
            } else if (currentMonth == 0) {
                prevMonth = 11;
                prevYear = yy - 1;
                nextYear = yy;
                daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
                nextMonth = 1;
                Log.d(tag, "**--> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                        + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                        + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
            } else {
                prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
                nextMonth = currentMonth + 1;
                nextYear = yy;
                prevYear = yy;
                daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
                Log.d(tag, "***---> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                        + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                        + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
            }

            int currentWeekDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
            trailingSpaces = currentWeekDay;

            Log.d(tag, "Week Day:" + currentWeekDay + " is "
                    + getWeekDayAsString(currentWeekDay));
            Log.d(tag, "No. Trailing space to Add: " + trailingSpaces);
            Log.d(tag, "No. of Days in Previous Month: " + daysInPrevMonth);

            if (cal.isLeapYear(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)))
                if (mm == 2)
                    ++daysInMonth;
                else if (mm == 3)
                    ++daysInPrevMonth;

            // Trailing Month days

            // Current Month Days
            for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
                Log.d(currentMonthName, String.valueOf(i) + " "
                        + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + " " + yy);
                if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth()) {
                    list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-"
                            + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
                } else {
                    list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-"
                            + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
                }
            }
        }
```